# Filter not working for multiple dropdown in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a drop-down filter for the table and have a drop-down filter for every column.
But the only filter on the first column is working and the rest of the filter is not working and element in column disappear when I try to filter them.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .bodycontent{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right:5%;
  }
  td{
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body >
    <div class="bodycontent">


<table id="table_format" class="table table-striped ">
                    <thead style="background-color: #70AD47">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Category
                              <select id="filterText" style="display:inline-block;" onchange="filterText()">
                              <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="School Nutrition">School Nutrition</option>
                              <option value="Food Safety">Food Safety</option>

                            </select>
                            </th>


                            <th>Course Title</th>
                            <th>Hours of Instruction
                             <select id="filterText" style="display:inline-block;" onchange="filterText()">
                              <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="one">1</option>
                              <option value="two">2</option>
                              <option value="three">3</option>

                            </select>
                            </th>

                            <th>Target Audience

                              <select id="filterText" style="display:inline-block;" onchange="filterText()">
                                <option disabled selected>Select Audience</option>
                                <option value="all">All</option>
                                <option value="Child Care Homes">Child Care Homes</option>
                                <option value="Child Care Professionals">Child Care Professionals</option>
                                <option value="Child Care Providers">Child Care Providers</option>
                                <option value="Child Nutrition Professionals">Child Nutrition Professionals</option>

                              </select>
                          </th>


                            <th>Key Area
                            <select id="filterText" style="display:inline-block;" onchange="filterText()">
                              <option disabled selected> Choose key area</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>

                            </select>
                          </th>

                            <th>Professional Standard Code
                              <select id="filterText" style="display:inline-block;" onchange="filterText()">
                              <option disabled selected> Choose Standard Code</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="1100">1100</option>           
                              <option value="1300">1300</option>
                              <option value="1310">1310</option>
                              <option value="1320">1320</option>


                              <option></option>                            
                            </select>
                          </th>
                            <th>OSSE DEL
                            <select id="filterText" style="display:inline-block;" onchange="filterText()">
                              <option disabled selected> Choose OSSE</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option>3</option>


                            </select>
                          </th>



                        </tr>
                    </thead>

  <tbody id="myTable">


  <tr class="content">


  <>School Nutrition</td>
  <td>Dietary Guidelines for Americans 2015</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>School Nutrition Staff, School Nutrition Managers, Child Care Staff</td>
  <td >1</td>
  <td >1300</td>
  <td >-</td>

 </tr>
 <tr class="content">

  <td>School Nutrition</td>
  <td>Nutrition 101 4th edition</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>Child Nutrition Professionals</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1300,1310, 1320</td>
  <td>3</td>

 </tr>


 <tr class="content">

  <td >School Nutrition</td>
  <td>CT5- Culinary Techniques - Preparing Breads and Baked Goods</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>School Nutrition Staff/Employees, Managers, and Directors</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2100,2130</td>
  <td">-</td>

 </tr>
<tr class="content">

  <td>School Nutrition</td>
  <td>CT6- Culinary Techniques - Using Seasonings</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>School Nutrition Staff/Employees, Managers, and Directors</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2100,2130</td>
  <td>-</td>

<tr class="content">

  <td>School Nutrition</td>
  <td>Portion
  Control</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>School Nutrition Staff/Employees, Managers, and Directors</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2120,2210</td>
  <td >-</td>

</tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


function filterText()
  {  
    var rex = new RegExp($('#filterText').val());
    if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()}else{
      $('.content').hide();
      $('.content').filter(function() {
      return rex.test($(this).text());
      }).show();
  }
  }



  function clearFilter()
  {
    $('.filterText').val('');
    $('.content').show();
  }





</script>

</body></html>
```

Is it possible to get the filter working for all columns? Also could multiple filters work at the same time.

Comment: You can't have duplicate ids on a page. Use classes instead.

Comment: Avoid W3 Schools like the plague. Better yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 1):

When you are using **id**, Javascript assumes that there is just one element with this **id**. Therefore, just the first select will work.

I changed the select elements into this:

```
<select class="filterText" style="display:inline-block;" onchange="filterText(this)">
    <option disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="School Nutrition">School Nutrition</option>
    <option value="Food Safety">Food Safety</option>
</select>
```

I changed the **id** to **class** and also passed the parameter **this** into the function. so that we can know which select element called **filterText** function.

Simply change your function into this:

```
function filterText(select)
  {  
    var rex = new RegExp($(select).children("option:selected").val());
    if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()} else {
          $('.content').hide();
          $('.content').filter(function() {
          return rex.test($(this).text());
          }).show();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "tightened" script that should probably do what you want.

It consists of two parts:

1. Collect all "valid" filter terms in the array `filters`. The elements in this array are small arrays themselves: 1. element is the position (column no.), 2. element is the actual filter string.
2. Step through all `<tr>`s. For each `<tr>` do the following:

   - The individual texts of all child-`<td>`s are collected into array `tds`
   - Inside the `filters.every()`-loop the filter strings are now compared to their corresponding column texts taken from `tds`.
     (Note: `every()` returns `true` for an empty array.)
   - `$('tr').toggle()` now shows or hides the current `<tr>` depending on the result of the `filters.every()`-loop.

P.S.: I changed the content of your table entries a little bit to make the filtering process a little bit more interesting ...

```js
$('.bodycontent').on('change','select',function(ev) {
  var filters=[];
  $('.filterText').each((k,s)=>{
    if (s.value!='all')                                    // exclude "all" as a non-selection
      filters.push([$(s).closest('th').index(),s.value]);  // return: [positon, filtertext]
  });
  $('.content').each(function(i,tr){
    let tds=$('td',tr).map((j,td)=>td.textContent).toArray(); // collects individual TD texts
    $(tr).toggle( filters.every(f=>tds[f[0]].search(f[1])>-1 ) ); // show or hide!
  });
});
```

```css
.bodycontent{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right:5%;
  }
  td{
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .filterText {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="bodycontent">

<table id="table_format" class="table table-striped ">
  <thead style="background-color: #70AD47">
    <tr>
      <th>Category
        <select class="filterText">
          <option disabled>Select</option>
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="School Nutrition">School Nutrition</option>
          <option value="Food Safety">Food Safety</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Course Title</th>
      <th>Hours of Instruction
        <select class="filterText">
          <option disabled>Select</option>
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Target Audience
        <select class="filterText">
          <option disabled>Select Audience</option>
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="Child Care Homes">Child Care Homes</option>
          <option value="Child Care Professionals">Child Care Professionals</option>
          <option value="Child Care Providers">Child Care Providers</option>
          <option value="Child Nutrition Professionals">Child Nutrition Professionals</option>

        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Key Area
        <select class="filterText">
          <option disabled> Choose key area</option>
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Professional Standard Code
        <select class="filterText">
          <option disabled> Choose Standard Code</option>
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="1100">1100</option>           
          <option value="1300">1300</option>
          <option value="1310">1310</option>
          <option value="1320">1320</option>
          <option></option>                            
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>OSSE DEL
        <select class="filterText">
          <option disabled> Choose OSSE</option>
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr class="content">
      <td>School Nutrition</td>
      <td>Dietary Guidelines for Americans 2015</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>School Nutrition Staff, School Nutrition Managers, Child Care Staff</td>
      <td >1</td>
      <td >1300</td>
      <td >-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>School Nutrition</td>
      <td>Nutrition 101 4th edition</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Child Nutrition Professionals</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1300,1310, 1320</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td >School Nutrition</td>
      <td>CT5- Culinary Techniques - Preparing Breads and Baked Goods</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>School Nutrition Staff/Employees, Managers, and Directors</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2100,2130</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>School Nutrition</td>
      <td>CT6- Culinary Techniques - Using Seasonings</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>School Nutrition Staff/Employees, Managers, and Directors</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2100,2130</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Food Safety</td>
      <td>Portion Control</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>School Nutrition Staff/Employees, Managers, and Directors</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2120,2210</td>
      <td >-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```